# How to make only part of an animation appear

Tags: animation, ms-office, powerpoint

I wanted to add a animation to a text in powerpoint, but only show part of it, currently it looks like this:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

What I want is that it only shows after it passes that bar, as if it's coming from the bar

Answer (score 0):

Place a black shape to the left of the bar and make sure it's in the foreground.